# Yocto - Sumo omitting the file xtables.c for compilation?

Tags: iptables, yocto

I have a Sumo Yocto build and I am trying to build the iptables. However, it is not building the xtables.c file. Here is the Sumo Yocto IP tables recipe

http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-extended/iptables/iptables_1.6.2.bb?h=sumo

Anything missing in the recipe which makes xtables.c not compile?
By not compiling I mean it is omitting this file for compilation.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I mean the compilation of xtables.c is omitted.

Comment: Share your recipe's directory tree.